# Eth1 interface not visible in ifconfig and not able to interact with other servers in centos6

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6

I just installed centos 6 on my virtual box but I am unable to find eth1 interface to make interactive with other virtual servers on my machine. Could you please help.

`ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:480 (480.0 b)  TX bytes:480 (480.0 b)`

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network
```

NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain

Comment: Can you check the output from `dmesg |grep eth` and tell us what's returned.

Comment: I have removed below file and reboot the server. It starts working automatically.                   # rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
Based on the below article https://www.ostechnix.com/solve-device-eth0-not-seem-present-delaying-initialization-error/

Comment: Anyways thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, simply remove the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and reboot your system.

## rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's true but after that there's need to create eth1 port and manually add all details in linux os

I found that eth1 port is not on web pages and in network-script

After the delete the command above and reboot system problem solved